# `Internal server error` when I try to view my wordpress page, and the same when I open it in website directly

Tags: php, wordpress

The site give an error like

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator, webmaster@stepprep.madoodles.com and inform them of the
>   time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may
>   have caused the error. More information about this error may be
>   available in the server error log. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server
>   Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to
>   handle the request.

`Apache Server at stepprep.com Port 80`
[stepprep is my site name]

It used to work perfectly a while ago and now it showed like this.. 
I can't even view my page after coding it in wordpress dashboard.

Comment: check apache error log file for real error. Mostly it could be related to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This error will come because of your code is not formated well. For example you forgot to close if condition parentheses, syntax error etc... Please check you code what you have written.